# ER Model of User Ratings

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I have many "Users" and each of them will have maximum of 5 "Services". The User should be able to Rate (0-5) on each Service. I would also like to persist the Avg Rating of the Users.

This is what I am thinking, but there could be a better way?

**User**

```
id | user_name | dob | ...
```

**Service (Fixed number of Services)**

```
id |service_description | service_code | avg_rating
```

**Rating:**

```
id | service_id | user_id | rating (0-5)
```

Comment: Is a user allowed to change rating?  Do you care about what they had rated it before?

Comment: Why do you want to store the average instead of calculating it?

Comment: How would you allocate for someone that wants a 3 level rating "High, Medium, Low" instead of a 5 level rating?

Comment: @RajMore Thanks for the questions. 1. User is allowed to change ratings 2. Yeah, calculating could be a better idea. I was not sure which would be a better approach from performance standpoint. 3. It would be Amazon style fixed 5 star rating (however I am also interested to learn how to keep the level of ratings flexible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an E/R diagram to depict the way a multiple ratings system can be implemented.  Note that I have used generic names for a lot of things.

[image]

Comment: Your solution is definitely scalable, this is however a relativly small feature request in our project which wont have many changes, I hope I get creation of 5 tables for this feature approved :). Thank you for the time and effort!

Comment: What would be the relation between Service and RatingValue, if I know the ratings will remain of the same type. I guess we will have one table less?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow users to change their rating and want to track their changes, you could simply do so by adding a `created_at` attribute to the **Rating** entity. In that way you allways know the current rating (last/highest timestamp) and you can also look up which changes the user did to his rating. A lot of database systems add this attribute by default, as well as the `last_changed` attribute.